# .htaccess rewrite rule - drop querystring from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm needing some help with my .htaccess file. What I have are pages with the query page=''. I've tried looking up some resources on rewriterule's but haven't found what I need.

So what I'm going for is like:

```
domain.com/sub/index.php?page=options to domain.com/sub/options.
```

futhermore I'd really like a trailing / like:

```
domain.com/sub/options/
```

Any help or resources to point me to would be appreciated.

Edit:

Have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

which seems to rewrite everything back to my root index.php

Answer (score 0):

For the redirection, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

For the trailing slash, you need to add it in your anchors on your pages.